# Job posting with starting date far away

Tags: job-search, start-date

I recently saw a job listing for a contract position with a starting date that is really far away.  The job listing is up and the company are looking for a person but the starting date is 6 months away.

Is this a red flag in any way or is it okay to apply to this job?

Comment: How is this even a red flag?

Comment: Is it not weird to get people to apply and then say "oh the starting date is 6month away' or is that normal for you? @Alrl

Comment: They just post in advance as much as they can, there can be a tons of reason. I just see it as optimising the chances to be seen. Jobs that are posted on a day and start ASAP are more of a red flag than good planning.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Don't see it as a red flag, If you like the job description and have the time, apply and find out why the long lead time.

Answer (score 1):

I have see this in a few situations that are 100% normal:

- college internships work this way.
- some teaching jobs work this way.

Some other situations can occur when the position is linked to the company winning a contract. The offer will be contingent on them winning the contract. If they don't win the job disappears.  One of my kids applied for a job with such a contingency. They interviewed in August, and would find out if they won in November; if they did win the job started in January.

It can also be linked to a position being funded after a certain date. I have been a part of contracts where a position wasn't funded until year 2 of the contract. There was no need for most of the help desk positions if the product hadn't started production.

Knowing before you apply is better than knowing after you have completed multiple interviews.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a red flag, a lot of companies plan ahead, be it from financial or people side.

But there is an important note to make, **6 months is not a short period of time and a lot of things can happen from now until then**. You can be hired and then, after 6 months, find out that the position is no longer available due to reason X, Y, Z. Be prepared for this and prioritize positions with the start dates either immediately or weeks/several months max.

Answer (score 1):

They are free to set whatever start date they want. You are free to not apply.

6 months out is not a practical target because it creates too much uncertainty. If you make a posting in January for a June start, and then someone is "hired" in February, that's several months in which things can change and they end up not working for you. For example, the person you hired may then keep applying to other jobs in March to see if he can do better, and discover that he can. From their side, what if your department loses funding in May and suddenly the deal is off?

The typical employee also doesn't want a job half a year from now. They want to start working now and start getting paid now. So you dramatically cut your pool of good candidates by setting the date so far out. It's much more sensible to simply wait until 1-2 months before your target date and make the posting then.

The company may have some legitimate reason for making it that far out (maybe they're hiring college students with a set graduation date). Or their HR may simply be confused or incompetent. Neither is necessarily bad in the sense of impacting your employment. If you are worried about the distant start date, you can negotiate an earlier start when you interview.

Answer (score 0):

I admit, I've not seen a posting that'll open up in 6 month, but that does not necessarily mean it's a red flag. There might be several reasons for a timeline like this, including spinning off a new department / business unit etc.

I'd say, if your profile is a fit, go ahead and apply. You'll have *plenty of time* to evaluate the offer also.